# XCode Target Duplication via Code

Tags: ios, xcode

Does anyone know a tried and tested way of duplicating XCode targets programatically?

I've tried this Gist based on the xcodeproj Ruby gem but it doesn't copy all the settings (like it would do if doing it through the XCode UI)

https://gist.github.com/ratazzi/f6d9217654d6605450a0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading I've actually taken a different approach with this.

Rather than duplicating targets and changing specific values I've utilised fastlane an in particular the 'set_info_plist' function to change values at build time that are specific to a target.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/#set_info_plist_value

This is useful for things like theming changes as per the build or Free/Paid applications environments where you want one single code base that behaves differently depending on the theme or nature of the application.